# Animating and adding random text in Android

Tags: android

I want to have a screen where I can insert text elements, taken from a database, at a random height in the screen, at random points in time, and then have it move from right to left, until it leaves the screen. The text elements should be clickable, giving me opportunity to change the fragment when one of them is clicked.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Android for quite some time, but not really coming close to a solution. The `ellipsize` option of TextView doesnt't actually sound right for my problem.

I think I have to write a custom view, adding elements and then displaying in in the inDraw() function, but I just do not get the hang of it. Can anyone point me to a good starting point for that?

Comment: share what have you tried so far and the problem you faced

Comment: I have spent hours looking for an entrance point to this problem to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
You can create a new animation and set it to your view like this:

```
Animation animMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.move);
```

And set it to you textview:

```
txtMessage.startAnimation(animMove);
```

And move.xml file can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

For more information you can have a look here :

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/#move

and also here:

http://android-er.blogspot.ro/2013/07/apply-animation-on-textview.html

Comment: Can I use this to dynamically add TextViews during runtime?

Comment: yes, you can add a textview and after that you can set to it the animation

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this out, and see if it works for me

Comment: Any possibilty to add a second animation after the first one has completed about 30%?

Comment: I can have only one animation at a time active, right?

Comment: you can use a set of animation like this:  AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
  Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(2000);
    animation.setStartOffset(300);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f);
    animation.setDuration(2000);
    animation.setStartOffset(300);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    text.startAnimation(set);

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, they have been a great help in figuring out how animation works in Android. However, for my problem, I finally found a different solution. Basically, I use 3 layered Recyclerviews, adding TextViews at random and autoscrolling them at different speed.